# Iteration to add class in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine

Here is what I have so far in my hello.jade file, I am aware that it is not finished, but I have no idea how to proceed.

```
for challenge in ["talks", "books", "blog"]
```

Here's what I would like in the output

```
<div class="talks"></div>
<div class="books"></div>
<div class="blog"></div>
```

So far, I am unable to find a way to use iteration to manipulate classes in Jade. Is this even possible? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the class attribute instead of the period shortcut like this:

```
for challenge in ["talks", "books", "blog"]
    div(class=challenge)
```

Comment: Many people forget that the `div.someClass` syntax is a nice shortcut but any attribute can be done the manual way in the parenthesis. Nice answer :)